# Theme Specific Wordpress Custom Fields

Tags: wysiwyg, custom-fields, wordpress, wpmu

I'm currently in the process of building a wordpress multi-site for a client.  I've completed aspect #1, which was creating Theme-1.  Theme-1 was built utilizing excessive amounts of the AdvancedCustomFields PLUGIN.

I'm working to build Theme-2, this one is the primary theme that will be utilized for all of the sub-sites created through the multi-site option.  The issue I'm having is that the AdvancedCustomFields are no longer an option, I need to build all of the customization into the functions.php file directly.

Is it possible to create custom fields through the theme directly - without utilizing a plugin?

I need the theme pages to have "Left Side" "Right Side" "Footer" as WYSIWYG editors.  So if someone goes to create a new page all of these field settings are there by default.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you ever happen to change the theme, you'll probably regret having this functionality into `functions.php`. But maybe not, to be sure see: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, using the [wp_editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) function to get the WYSIWYG functionality.  See [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49901/post-custom-metabox-textarea-using-wp-editor) on the WordPress stackexchange site.  It's demonstrated as a plugin, but you could just as easily put the code in your theme.